# How to send ascii characters through serial in python?

Tags: python-2.7, ascii, ubuntu-16.04, putty, pyserial

I want to send 3 numbers (integers) through serial port in ascii format. I use putty terminal to see the receiving data on the other end. The problem is that putty doesn't shows anything except strings. I tried to use the ord() function to get the ascii format but I cannot see anything on putty. Is it just a putty problem with ascii format, or I don't send data at all? How can I be sure that I send the data in the correct format (ascii)? 
I am new to python, so sorry if this sounds trivial.
I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Python 2.7.12.
Thank you in advance!

```
#!/opt/bin/python
import serial
import time

camera = [0, 0, 0]

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
print (ser.name)
print ("Port Open")
time.sleep(2)
while ser.isOpen():
    for i in range(1):
        #ser.write(b'5')
        #ser.write(chr(5)) 
        #ser.write(5)
        ser.write(ord(str(camera[0])))
        #ser.write(bytes(camera))
        print(camera)
        time.sleep(1)
        camera[1] = camera[1] + 1

ser.close()
```

Comment: Have you already tried to write just a string? `ser.write("test")`
the best way to open a serial port is to use the `with` function:
`with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600) as ser:`
With this method you don't have to think about the `ser.close` because automatically close itself. As first thing try to figure out if the problem is with the communication parameters (eg. wrong baud rate, parity etc etc). After that try to write some string just like this `ser.write("test")`. You can also try to write to the serial port using the bash, like this: `echo "test" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @CarloZanocco I face no problem with sending strings. The problem comes when I try something different than ser.write(str(...))